# Как понять на что расходуется память в linux?

Tags: linux, память, top

Есть процесс, который по данным top потребляет 13,3% оперативной памяти. Однако по данным free используется памяти - 87,1%. Как понять куда ушла остальная память?

Ниже скриншот вывода top с сортировкой по RES, на котором видно, что процесс flussonic потребляет 13,3%, потребление памяти всеми остальными процессами - незначительное и не может влиять на значение Used, также я на всякий случай сделал в top сортировку по VIRT и обнаружил ещё один процесс, запрашивающий большие объёмы виртуальной памяти - Flussonic-thumb, но резидентная память у него всего 0,1%

Дополнение. Чтобы не возникал вопрос "как сопоставить отображаемую разными утилитами информацию про использование памяти", при дальнейшем исследовании проблемы я решил не использовать утилиты free, top и smem, а информацию получал из /proc, для процессов flussonic и flussonic-thumbnailer я получал данные об используемой резидентной и виртуальной памяти из /proc/"$PID"/status, данные получались каждые 5 минут и по ним строился график.

Сейчас, спустя месяц дополняю вопрос. По графику видно, что есть некая внутидневная динамика, используемая резидентная память процесса flussonic в зависимости от дневной нагрузки сервера колеблется от 3.5 до 5 Гбайт, но на более долгих временных прмежутках видно что ухода за эти пределы нет. А вот значение Used, которое вычислялось из данных в /proc за это же время увеличилось с 24 до 28 Гбайт, а если взять график за 3 месяца, то видно, что Used увеличилось с 12 до 28 Гбайт, память "течёт", причём графики процессов flussonic и flussonic-thumbnailer доказывают, что текут вовсе не самые нагруженные процессы, тогда что течёт, ядро? Как решить эту задачу?

[image: top-RES]

[image: top-VIRT]

[image: flussonic-RES]
[image: flussonic-VIRT]
[image: flussonic-thumbnailer-RES]
[image: flussonic-thumbnailer-VIRT]
[image: memory-usage]
[image: memory-usage-long]

Comment: Потребление памяти — штука сложная, покажите конкретные показания всех программ

Comment: потому что часть памяти может быть зарезервирована под кэш. эта часть может быть освобождена если потребуется

Comment: Таким образом, вопрос про кэш перетек в вопрос "память в программе течет". 
Но это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что "течёт" не программа, а ядро.
Про кэш было предположение с самого начала, но сброс кэша командой
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
не помогает, значит дело не в кэше
Вопрос в том, что я не могу понять где именно самый большой расход памяти: в  каком-то процессе, в ядре, если в ядре то где именно?

Comment: Вы начали смешивать два разных вопроса в одном. Что расходует память вам показали утилиты, команды и примеры. Далее как работает каждая конкретная утилита и почему у вас там что-то не срастается - это отдельный вопрос. Для начала нужно разобраться, что такое `VIRT` и `RES` память... Ядро у них потекло...

Comment: RES - резидентная часть памяти процесса, SHR - разделяемая часть памяти процесса, VIRT - виртуальная память процесса, то есть вся память которую видит процесс, но не занимает её, складывать между собой эти столбцы нельзя, но даже если сложить получится сумма значительно меньшая чем used

Comment: я вместо top использовал smem, которая вычисляет PSS - пропорциональную память, которую как раз можно складывать, сумма PSS всех процессов даёт 16,2%, а free показывает, что под процессы использовано 67,2%, вопрос куда ушли оставшиеся 51% и почему эта величина растёт?

Comment: Давайте обратимся к изначальной проблеме - что это за программа, которая плохо себя ведет? Очень может быть, что программа лопает какие-то ресурсы (и не освобождает их), и под это дело уже ядро занимает память.

Comment: По сути вопрос-то, хороший, но другой -- **как сопоставить отображаемую разными утилитами информацию про использование памяти?**

Comment: Мое мнение, в вопросе не хватает конкретики, скринов или точных данных которые выдают утилиты. Если их не указывать, что-то обсуждать бессмысленно.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Теперь в нём есть графики, которые я строил в течение месяца.

Comment: А что творится в других папках /proc/PID/? В частости, в ./fd/ ./map_files/? не растет ли количество дескрипторов?

Comment: Что именно отображает Used? Т.е. как именно вычислялось это значение из `/proc`? Использовались ли данные из '/proc/[pid]/smaps' ? Есть ли у вас полная копия `/proc' месячной давности чтобы сравнить за счет чего именно возникло увеличение?

Comment: Used вычислялось из /proc/meminfo как MemTotal-MemFree-Buffers-Cached-Slab
Про полную копию /proc это конечно хороший вопрос, /proc же обычным способом скопировать невозможно, так как в нём есть файлы, содержащие всю опаративную память, а также файлы, при чтении которых пойдут запросы к ядру.

Comment: Имеет смысл скопировать, во-первых, то что использовалось для подсчета, т.е. meminfo. А во-вторых, данные по процессам, т.е. /proc/*/smaps. Насколько я знаю, то именно через `smaps` можно получить наиболее полную и актуальную информацию в разрезе процессов. Т.е. придется агрегировать, но с другой стороны это же и покажет, где используется память.

Comment: Кстати по поводу роста количества дескрипторов. Процесс flussonic имеет 335 от: из них: 135 - файловые, 178 - типа socket и 22 типа pipe. Какие из них влияют на расход памяти?

Comment: Есть ещё мысли?

Comment: Я бы получил показатели памяти для всех процессов из smaps (используя хотя бы https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#process-management сохранить бы `memory_info` и `memory_maps` для каждого процесса) сейчас и через некоторое время и сравнил, за счет чего возникает увеличение.

Answer (score 2):

Простой, но не точный вариант - ставите htop и смотрите на соответствующие столбики
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленое - то что слопали программы.

Желтое - кэш файловой системы.

Синее - разного рода буферы ядра.

На долго работающей машине, как правило, кэш съедает всю свободную память, но это не страшно - если памяти не хватает, он просто сбрасывается на диск.

Comment: htop в отличие от top показывает не процессы, а потоки, если просуммировать все значения в столбце в htop - получится ерунда, именно поэтому я использую top. Ещё есть инструмент smem, который как раз умеет сумму столбцов выводить. Проблема в другом.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3,7Gi       2,0Gi       430Mi       180Mi       1,3Gi       1,2Gi
Swap:         3,9Gi       786Mi       3,1Gi
```

buff/cache отображается желтым в htop и может быть освобожден как только понадобится. [Не паникуйте - это нормально](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: Я в курсе, что buffers и cache могут быть освобождены ядром как только появится некий процесс, который запросит больше памяти, поэтому то что занято под buffers и cache - это на самом деле не "занято", а "свободно". Проблема в другом, я дополнил свой вопрос, чтобы было понятнее.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -HP "VmRSS:[ \t]+[1-9]" /proc/[0-9]*/status 2>/dev/null |\
sed -r 's/\/proc\/(.*)\/status:VmRSS:[ \t]+([^\t ]+)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z]+)/printf "%-10s | %-20s | %s\n" "PID: \1" "size: \2\3"  "command: `cat \/proc\/\1\/cmdline 2>\/dev\/null`"/g' |\
/bin/bash | sort -t':' -k '3,3' -nr | more
```

Достаточно *"дурацкая"* и длинная команда, которая выведет сортированную информацию по утилизации памяти. Некий аналог `top` или `htop` что делает ее написание не особо целесообразным.

По логике, для каждого процесса мы проверяем поле VMRSS, где указана физическая величина используемого ОЗУ пространства, без записи в виртуальное хранилище и далее форматируем, сортируем.

Вывод будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```txt
PID: 17642 | size: 78784kB        | command: fb_inet_server
PID: 10231 | size: 73256kB        | command: fb_inet_server
PID: 4311  | size: 69968kB        | command: fb_inet_server
PID: 22499 | size: 69940kB        | command: fb_inet_server
PID: 1843  | size: 43508kB        | command: //usr/local/tander/bin/_python2.5...
PID: 2363  | size: 33548kB        | command: /usr/local/tander/i586-pc-linux-gnu/usr/bin/uwsgi...
PID: 30211 | size: 29864kB        | command: fb_inet_server
PID: 5423  | size: 28456kB        | command: fb_inet_server
```

Comment: Ба, кто-то еще кроме меня Firebird юзает :)

Comment: @gbg =) ага и версия 1.5 *грустный гарольд*

Comment: Вы не поверите, аналогично.